# Powershell script to map to network drive and download files

Tags: networking, powershell

I am a newbie to powershell. I want to write a script to do the following

Check if I have mapped to a network drive
If not, map to it
Once mapped, check the files in 4 folders at a path on the network drive 
If the files are newer to those I compare to on a local drive, copy them ie. only copy new/updated files

Any help with this would be great as I need a starting position to take on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `net use` to determine if the drive is mapped or not:

```
net use s:
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    net use s: \\server\share
}

$folders = @{local = 'c:\path1';remote='s:\path1'},
           @{local = 'c:\path2';remote='s:\path2'}
$folders | Foreach {xcopy $_.remote $_.local /E /C /H /R /Y /D /I}
```

Don't forget the existing console tools tend to work just fine in PowerShell and sometimes are the easiest way to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I would be grateful if you give the same example in a batch/console file as I dont want to just go down the road of using powershell for the sake of it.

Comment: Why did you target this question at Powershell then?

Comment: Because I wasn't sure which was the better approach to take. I want to be able to do this with either a batch file or powershell without having to use any 3rd party plugins etc.

Comment: This answer doesn't use any 3rd party plugins.  Xcopy.exe and net.exe are standard Windows utilities installed by Windows.